# Fetchmail doesn't recognize my procmail binary

Tags: procmail, fetchmail

**My problem:** after running `fetchmail` I get this error:

```
/Users/User/.fetchmailrc:7: syntax error at -d
```

My `.fetchmailrc` file looks like this:

```
set daemon 300
set nobouncemail
set invisible
poll pop.gmail.com withi proto POP3
user 'my-email@address' there with password 'my-password' is 'my-mac-user' here
options keep ssl
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"*
```

I have `procmail` installed on my Mac.

**My question:** How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo on the first line, it says "withi" instead of "with".

procmail's -d option sets the delivery mode which needs root priviledges, are you running it as root?

Also, try to use ' instead of "

Comment: I tried now 'chow root /usr/bin/procmail' to add to root the procmail but still the same error I get.

Comment: If you're not root, try sudo

Comment: procmail is already root using sudo! But if you mean to use sudo before fetchmail, that one also returns the same syntax  error ! I'm afraid it is because of version of fetchmail! I'm using 6.3.22

Comment: Did you correct the error I mentioned?

Comment: withi I changed also! And sudo also!

Comment: Try to use ' instead of "

Comment: I changed also " by ' but the same error! I removed the -d %T part of the string to see what can happen, now error is sh: /usr/bin/procmail no such file Or directory!

Comment: You don't have procmail installed!

Comment: when I use 'procmail -v' I get the description! I also setup a  .procmailrc file to redirect some mails! It can't be! Also in usr/bin/ directory procmail exist!

Comment: So now you have another question to ask: Why doesn't fetchmail recognize my procmail binary?

Comment: I changed the title of question as you said! Interesting is I have another Mac which is running the same codes just different gmail Account but other is working well!

Comment: Please (!) open a new question.

Comment: ! The problem solved by its own after restarting the Mac! I coudn't think what could be the reason for it.